# Adjacency list model for site hierarchy, how to retrieve all pages in this particular order?

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, adjacency-list-model

I have to admin I'm not a SQL-guru, maybe this query is really simple but I can't manage to write it. Basically all pages are arranged using the adjacency list model (I'm tracking the deep too):

```
+----+---------------+-------------------+-----------+
| id | title         | level | position  | parent_id |
+----+---------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Home          | 0     | 0         | null      |
+----+---------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  2 | Resources     | 0     | 1         | null      |
+----+---------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  3 | About         | 0     | 2         | null      |
+----+---------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  4 | Documents     | 1     | 0         | 2         |
+----+---------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  5 | Tutorials     | 1     | 1         | 2         |
+----+---------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

Note that position is unique among the same parent.

What I'm trying to achieve is to **sort by parent and position**, but the **parent category should be listed right before** its children. This is obvious and doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM PAGE p
ORDER BY parent_id, position
```

And result is the first table. What I need is the following:

```
+----+---------------+-------------------+-----------+
| id | title         | level | position  | parent_id |
+----+---------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Home          | 0     | 0         | null      |
+----+---------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  2 | Resources     | 0     | 1         | null      | // Parent of 4, 5
+----+---------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  4 | Documents     | 1     | 0         | 2         | // Child of Resource
+----+---------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  5 | Tutorials     | 1     | 1         | 2         | // Child of Resource
+----+---------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  3 | About         | 0     | 2         | null      |
+----+---------------+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

Is this possible in MySQL, not supporting recursion?

Comment: This task requires recursion (as you already wrote) and MySQL does not support common table expressions (CTE). So it cannot be done declaratively using SQL in MySQL. You have to do procedurally. The adjacency list model is fixed for you?

Comment: @Fabian Nope, it's not fixed.

Comment: A simple solution would be to store the full path for each node as a string, e.g., '0001/0002/0004' for your Documents entry. Cf the [slides of Bill Karwin](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back), starting at slide 55. That could be mixed the adjacency list model or, e.g., a closure table, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use self-joins when you can limit the query. Or try a nested-set or celko-tree.